# Go Language: A way to tokenize a string

Tags: string, go

I have a Go Program where I need to search through multiple strings for a specific pattern. The Strings all look like this:

```
 Destination: 149.164.31.169 (149.164.31.169)
```

I'd like to just extract the IP `149.164.31.169`, either the middle one or the one in parenthesis, they will always be the same. In Java I would do something along the lines of using a string tokenizer to gather the part of the string I need, but I didnn't find a function similar in go.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 20):

You can just split on spaces and take the middle one:

```
s := "Destination: 149.164.31.169 (149.164.31.169)"
parts := strings.Split(s, " ")
if len(parts) != 3 {
    panic("Should have had three parts")
}
println(parts[1])
```

There are lots of other approaches. The `strings` package is the place to look. Of course if you need something much more complex, you can look at `regex` for regular expressions, but that'd be overkill here. If you really need a tokenizer, look at `text/scanner`, but again, that's way too much for this.

Comment: Thank you, this worked great, and is very similar to tokenizer.

Comment: How do we handle multiple separators ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `fmt.Sscanf` for this:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func extractIP(s string) string {
   var ip string
   fmt.Sscanf(s, "Destination: %v", &ip)
   return ip
}

func main() {
   ip := extractIP("Destination: 149.164.31.169 (149.164.31.169)")
   fmt.Println(ip == "149.164.31.169")
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/fmt#Sscanf